# CakePHP allow form to submit javascript code

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I am working on a legacy CakePHP website. The website is on CakePHP 2.5.

In one of the forms, currently it will not submit and will just freeze the form submission, if I entered certain JavaScript code.

For example, entering the following in the form's textarea, the form will not submit. I need to remove this restriction.

```
<script>alert</script>
```

I want to ALLOW users to enter and submit any JavaScript code in this form. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? Save Javascript code on database?

Comment: Yes, I want to let the user enter JavaScript codes in a form, and then save this into the database. Then, I will output this JavaScript code on a page. I know this is very risky, but let's put the risk aside first.

Comment: When you insert any text on the form, cakephp will store them on database. You must ensure field data type on table is correct. MySQL, for instance, for this field type should be TEXT or LONGTEXT. Try check field type on database and check out CakePHP Model files and ensure  usage of correct validators.

Comment: There is no out of the box functionality in CakePHP that would inspect form contents and prevent submission. That is most likely something specific implemented in your application (or even in the browser that you are using), which you'd have to debug accordingly. Without seeing all the involved HTML/JS, nobody here can really help you with that.